# JFrame not disposing when I press escape

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I am Trying to make the program respond when the button ESC is clicked so that it will dispose the jframe. I am Not sure what the problem is but it seems to be in the if statement in the main menu.

*Note: te is the object name for the class (Text Editor)

This part is in the main method

```
f.add(text);
    f.addKeyListener(te);
    f.setVisible(true);

    while(true){
       if (exiting == true){
           f.dispose();
       }

    }
```

This part is outside the main method

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
        exiting = true;

    }
}
```

Comment: `I am Not sure what the problem is` - did you do any debugging?. Did you add a print statement to the KeyListener to see if the code is executed?

Comment: It seems that you have an infinite loop on the EDT, that will freeze the GUI. [Take a look at this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

Comment: i tried to put Thread.sleep(10); inside the loop but it still didnt work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `KeyListener`s, as a general rule, the component they are attached MUST have key board focus in order to be triggered.

Instead, use a key binding...

```
InputMap im = getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
ActionMap am = getRootPane().getActionMap();

im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0), "cancel");
am.put("cancel", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        dispose();
    }
});
```

See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Because of the power of the `Action` API, I would create a basic "dispose" action to start with:

```
public class DisposeWindowAction extends AbstractAction {

    private Window window;

    public DisposeWindowAction(Window window) {
        this.window = window;
        putValue(NAME, "Dispose");
        putValue(ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS, 0));
    }

    public Window getWindow() {
        return window;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        getWindow().dispose();
    }

}
```

I'd then bind this to the `ActionMap`...

```
am.put("cancel", new DisposeWindowAction(this));
```

Why you ask?  Because you can then use the same `Action` in `JMenuItem`s and `JButton`s`....

```
JButton disposeButton = new JButton(new DisposeWindowAction(this));
...
```

(You can use the same instance of the `Action`, but you get the idea) and now the user has something like three more ways to dispose of the window...

See [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

there is an easier way to add a listener to the jframe. All you have to do is create a keylistener overriding keypressed and then check what type of object e.getComponent() is. If it is a window type you can call dispose on it when the escape key is pressed.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    If(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
        If( e.getComponent() instanceof Window){
            ((Window)e.getComponent()).dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

You can of course change window to JFrame, and put the two if statements together.

Also you do not need the while loop.

Comment: `KeyListener` is a poor choice, the moment that any component that can grab keyboard focus will cause your `KeyListener` to be ignored

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ahh, I did not know about key bindings, I figured key listerners were the only way to capture key events. Thanks for the tip.